# Utility function not evaluating correctly numpy python

Tags: python, numpy, economics

The answer should be 117.4, I'm getting 9982.3... Not sure what the problem is but here's my code:

```
def util(c,p,alpha):
    mu = 0
    for i in range(0,len(c)):
        m = p[i]*(c[i]**(1-alpha))
        mu += m
    return mu**(1/(1-alpha))

omega = 0.495
c = np.array([100,200,1000])
p = np.array([omega, omega, 1-2*omega])
alpha = 5
```

EDIT: I'm not sure if there is an error with my math or with the function I wrote, I am asking if my math fits the code that I wrote.

I'm solving this equation for mu: U(mu) = E[U(c)] with payoffs c, and probability distribution p, as above. U(c) has the form c^(1-alpha)/(1-alpha).

```
U(mu) = mu^(1-alpha)/(1-alpha) = E[U(c)] = (omega*c1^(1-alpha)+omega*c2^(1-alpha)+(1-2*omega)*c3^(1-alpha))/(1-alpha)

=> mu = (omega*c1^(1-alpha)+omega*c2^(1-alpha)+(1-2*omega)*c3^(1-alpha))^(1/(1-alpha))
```

Comment: `util(c,p,alpha)` actually returns 9.99558 for me.

Comment: that is extra confusing...

Comment: @bpr You've got to give us a little more to go on than: There's a problem here. This is not enough information to help us find the bug.

Comment: hope that last edit was helpful

Comment: Change `alpha = 5` to `alpha = 5.0`, since you want floating-point arithmetic.  You're not using numpy's vectorization: `mu = np.sum(p*(c**(1-alpha)))` is better.

Comment: @Alok-- you should post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that Python is doing integer division.  Python 2 does integer division with `/`, unless you do `from __future__ import division` (see [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)).  So you need to change at least one of your operands to a floating-point value.  You can do this by setting `alpha = 5.0` instead of `alpha = 5`.  Or you can write `1.0 - alpha` instead of `1 - alpha`.

Also, you can make your code a bit more compact by using numpy's vectorized operations.  Your `util` function can be shortened to:

```
def util(c, p, alpha):
    mu = np.sum(p * (c ** (1.0 - alpha)))
    return mu ** (1 / (1.0 - alpha))
```